# Java Integer Array Rotation (Left)

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I have a simple rotation function which takes an array and a number to rotate the numbers left

e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5] & 2` - output: `[3,4,5,1,2]`.

I want to know the most efficient way of completing this function, whether it would be to convert the int array into a string a splice it or whether to copy the array or to convert to an `List<Integer>`.

If anyone wants additional information please ask!

my solution at the moment:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    int lengthOfArray = a.length;
    int[] temp = new int[lengthOfArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++){
        int newLocation = (i + (lengthOfArray - d)) % lengthOfArray;
        temp[newLocation] = a[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current solution and why you think it *isn't efficient*?

Comment: You don't need an extra `collection` to perform this operation. You can do it using arrays itself.

Comment: @NicholasK could explain please?

Comment: Read the documentation of [`Collections.rotate(List, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int)).  Apply it to an array.

Comment: @aidan22 : Why don't you first store all the input in the array and then shift it to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do it with `O(n)` complexity is as below along with handling of valid  `shifts int[] arr:` is an int array,  `n=length` of an array,   d=how many shifts required.

```
    public int[] leftRotate(int[] arr, int n, int d) {

    int rot = 0;
    int[] marr = new int[n];
    if (d < 0 || d == 0 || d>n) {
        return arr;
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if (i < n - d) {
                marr[i] = arr[i + d];
            } else {
                marr[i] = arr[rot];
                rot++;
            }

        }

        return marr;
    }

}

    public void GetArray(int[] arr, int n, int d) {

    int[] arr1 = leftRotate(arr, n, d);
    for (int j : arr1) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int n = arr.length;

    Test2 obj = new Test2();
    obj.GetArray(arr, n, 2);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this one

```
void Rotate(int arr[], int d, int n) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) 
            leftRotatebyOne(arr, n); 
    } 

    void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int i, temp; 
        temp = arr[0]; 
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; 
        arr[i] = temp; 
    }
```

and to call this invoke method like below

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
Rotate(arr, 2, 5);
```

Comment: it's a problem solving exercise from a book, trying to solve with just the two parameters.

Comment: I stated it's an exercise were I can only use these parameters, I am looking for more efficient solutions to my answer and as stated by @NicholasK I did not nor can not down vote you.